# How do I know my web service provider supports mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to set up an angular2 site using Nodejs and for db I read that mongodb is really good. Now before I install it even locally, how do I know that my website service provider supports it? Or is installing it as simple as copy/pasting the db folder/filer to ftp?

(My provider: https://www.zone.ee/en/)

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and is off-topic. Just check with your hosting provider and see what they offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have root access to the machine you're hosting on (like if you can run commands from the command-line such as `node` and `npm`) then chances are you can install mongoDB no problem.  You may want to ask your provider, though.

MongoDB is great, but you can always get around the need for it by using plain-old JSON...

Comment: Yes, I was able to access my server using gitbash and ssh and I was able to npm install mongodb.

Comment: @yodalr Nice.  If you have it installed that's good, but mongoDB runs as a separate program/service as `mongod` [mongo daemon] so you need to be able to run not only a node instance in one window, but a mongo instance in another -- at least that's how I do it on my remote machine when I run mongo.  If you can do that, then you're golden (because mongod will give you an IP:PORT to connect your node.js program to.

Comment: can I run this mongod from the same gitbash cmd?

Comment: @yodalr Maybe!  I am not sure how.  Open a fresh question, maybe other people are wondering the same.